# TensorFlow embedding_lookup_sparse optimization

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, embedding

I have some `embedding_vectors` and I need to use the following `new_embeddings`:

```
new_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse(
    params=embedding_vectors,
    sp_ids=some_ids,
    sp_weights=None,
)
```

The problem is that `some_ids` is really big and remarkably sparsed *but* constant for the given data 2-D tensor. My pipeline includes the evaluation of its `indices`, `values` and `shape` which I use directly with the `sparse_placeholder` in training loop to feed up the `some_ids` placeholder.

Unfortunately it is very slow. It seems that in every training step the `some_ids` are converted to dense tensor which seems really unnecessary and strange. Am I right about this convertion and is there any alternative for `embedding_lookup_sparse`?

Answer (score 0):

I find [tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_tensor_dense_matmul) is mush faster than `tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse()`.